# VS code in WSL2 doesn't recognise C compilers

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I'm trying to use VS code in wsl2 ubuntu for C/C++ development.

I am following the official guide for reference.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-wsl

**(guide run helloworld.cpp step 3)**

But when I run no compiler configurations are shown and only (gdb) Launch is shown
[image]

Comment: And step 6, `whereis g++`, did show a path to g++?

Comment: Can you go to the shell and execute `whereis g++` and `whereis gdb` and share the output, please?

Comment: Yes I can fully use the compilers in the terminal.